# Use sed (or other command line) to replace a set of characters with a different set

Tags: command-line, sed

I need to invert a DNA text string by changing all the A's to T's, T's to A's, C->G, and G->C.

Can I elegantly handle this in sed (or other command line) without a whole chain of sed global replace commands?

Comment: @OMG Ponies sed can alter the source if the user running the command has edit privs and you use the '-i' switch, for in place editing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is how you do it with sed

```
$ echo "test ATCG GATC test" | sed 'y/ATCG/TAGC/'
test TAGC CTAG test
```

Comment: interesting, was not aware of the y option to sed

Answer (score 6):

use tr.
    cat file | tr ATCG TAGC

Comment: Oh great, this is just what I was looking for. I originally had a solution where I'd change all the A's and G's to some other character (X and Y) then do another pass where I'd change everything back, but that seemed stupid.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: far superior ? not really. And UUOC. `tr ATCG TAGC < file`